# Crystal Report Formula to show records where specific field not null?

Tags: crystal-reports, formula

I am using SQL Joins to retrieve data from multiple tables. I am grouping records by department. I want to show only those records where Department Name not null. I can control this through JOINS but in some other scenarios I need to show null department records. Is there any formula to make it possible? My current formula is:

```
if {?ParamGrp} = "Department" then
(
  "Department Name:  " &{tblEmployees.DepartmentName}
)
else if {?ParamGrp} = "" then
(
  ""
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Crystal has a built in formula `ISNULL()` for situations where a value is literally null, and not just an empty string. You can splice it into your existing code easily:

```
IF ISNULL({tblEmployees.DepartmentName}) OR {?ParamGrp} = "" THEN
    ""
ELSE IF {?ParamGrp} = "Department" THEN
    "Department Name:  " & {tblEmployees.DepartmentName}
```

Comment: Still showing records which are not associated with any department. I do not want to display records where department name is null. Not `ParamGrp`.

Comment: Swap it out then. Replace `ISNULL({?ParamGrp})` with `ISNULL({tblEmployees.DepartmentName})`

Comment: Already tried. Maybe I am doing something wrong. Basically, `paramGrp` contains my `groupby` clause. If I want to group by department or branch or nationality.

Comment: @AliSheikh I tried rewriting the logic to perform the Null check first. Does that help?